# Run time smart contract random number generator

Tags: solidity, randomness

I am wondering what problems the following function could have in generating a random number in runtime. I understand miners can manipulate transactions if environmental variables such as block.hash, or block.timestamp or block.number are solely relied on as sources of randomness, but if a run-time variable is added as an external or off-chain source, I do not see what potential issue it get can. In spirit, this is what Chainlink VRF is doing although much simplified. Any insight is much appreciated.

```
function genRandomNumbers(uint256 salt) public pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 seed = salt + block.timestamp;
    return uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(seed));
```

Comment: if the random number is not going to influence huge amount of money you can just use Difficulty as random number. But if this random number will be used to decide the amount of payout (sort of profit or loss) then if the transaction returns more profit than transaction fees miners receive from block processing, your contract likely to get hacked by the miners.

Comment: block's hash is already produced by keccak, you can save gas just by using block's hash as random number directly and save on gas fees

Comment: `blockhash` is not a run time random number though. And how can this contract be hacked by miners? Again, it is a pure function in a deployed contract. Miners are out of the picture when the contract is called.

Comment: "ow can this contract be hacked by miners" before processing your transaction they check what random number you are going to generate, and adjust the input for the correct output

Comment: "Miners are out of the picture when the contract is called" that was very funny!

Comment: " is not a run time random number" only if you are thinking there is going to be many transactions executed by your contract in a block, but in that case block's hash can be used as seed

Comment: There is nothing funny. You can run this function in a test contract. It does not create a transaction on blockchains if being called by an EOA. Being called by a another contract is another story.